# FileOpen() always fails with Error 5002 - Bad Filename

Tags: metatrader5

I do correctly get the MetaTrader safe folder to write files to via

```
string path = TerminalInfoString(TERMINAL_DATA_PATH) + "\\MQL5\\Files\\";
```

however,

```
int f = FileOpen(path + filename, FILE_READ | FILE_WRITE | FILE_CSV , '\n');
```

always fails due to the 5002 error - bad filename

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind to also do a **`Print( "[" + path + filename + "]" );`** and copy/paste the reported values?

Comment: A . . . . . . ?